# Audio Stop Function With JS

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have been trying to make a stop button for a soundboard that I have been making, however, the Console keeps saying that `Uncaught TypeError: audio.pause is not a function
    at Stop (test2.html:205)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test2.html:113)`, even though I have defined `audio`. (I cut out many unnecessary lines)

I have made sure that I have spelled and camel cased everything correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<button onclick="Kommunizm()">Kommunizm</button>
<button onclick="Lenin()">Lenin</button>
<button onclick="OurGame()">Our Game</button>
<button onclick="USSR()">USSR</button>
<button onclick="Stop()">Stop (But do you really want to?)</button>
<button id="About">About</button>

<script>
var audio;
var music = [
"Soviet_Union_national_anthem_(instrumental),_1977.oga",
"Internationale_orchestral_arrangement.ogg",
"Korobeiniki.ogg",
"y2mate.com - ussr_ymca_parody_YV2WuSJ9GcA_320kbps.ogg"
];

//Now why is this disobeying my command?
function Stop() {
for (i=0;i<music.length;i++){
audio = "audio" + i; 
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
}
}

function Kommunizm(){
audio0 = new Audio(music[0]);
audio0.play();
}

function Lenin(){
audio1 = new Audio(music[1]);
audio1.play();
}

function OurGame(){
audio2 = new Audio(music[2]);
audio2.play();
}

function USSR(){
audio3 = new Audio(music[3]);
audio3.play();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `audio = "audio" + i; ` does not select a tag. That just creates a string and strings don't have a pause function.

Comment: If I were you I would not try to create so many dynamic elements and only add one to the page and find that using `document.getElementById` then update the `src` and call play on that. That way you only have to find one element and call `pause` to stop the sound from playing. Otherwise you are going to have to maintain an array of your audio objects and loop over it calling stop on all of them. Another approach would be adding an audio tag for each sound and then just finding all of them with `document.querySelectorAll('audio')` and loop over that to call stop on all the elements.

Comment: @AdamH I should have thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comments I threw together this quick example of a generic soundboard that is built from some JSON. This should meet all your requirements and make your life easier in the future. If you don't understand how or why something is working, let me know and ill expand on that a bit.

```js
const sounds = [
 {name: 'Kommunizm', location: 'Soviet_Union_national_anthem_(instrumental),_1977.oga'},
  {name: 'Lenin', location: 'Internationale_orchestral_arrangement.ogg'},
  {name: 'OurGame', location: 'Korobeiniki.ogg'},
  {name: 'USSR', location: 'y2mate.com - ussr_ymca_parody_YV2WuSJ9GcA_320kbps.ogg'}
];

const container = document.getElementById('button_container');
sounds.forEach(function(sound){
 let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.setAttribute('type', 'button')
  btn.setAttribute('data-source', sound.location);
  btn.setAttribute('data-name', sound.name);
  btn.innerHTML = sound.name;
  btn.addEventListener("click", playSound)
  container.appendChild(btn)
  
  let audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.setAttribute('id', sound.name);
  audio.setAttribute('autoplay', false);
  audio.setAttribute('src', sound.location);
  container.appendChild(audio);
});

function stop(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio'), function(aud) {
    aud.stop();
  });
}

function playSound(){
 let player = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-name'));
  if (player)
   player.play();
}
```

```html
<div id="button_container">

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="stop">
Stop All Sounds
</button>
```